# Send Only Current Page object to the template (django)

Tags: python, django, django-models, detailsview

I am learning django from MDN.And i was working on locallibrary.There i got one problem.
I want to send only books on author page but not all book,only current page's author book.

If url is

### /author/1

then sent only book of author id 1, not all

In **AuthorDetailView** i tried **context['books']=Book.objects.filter(author__exact=Author.id)**.
but it give error

```
**TypeError at /catalog/author/1**

**int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DeferredAttribute'**
```

When i write **context['books']=Book.objects.filter(author__exact=1)**
then it send only authorid 1's book on all page.
on **author/2**.

so i want to send authorid 2's book on **author/2**. 3's book on **author/3**.
But not all books on everypage.

It doesn't make sense to send all objects when needed few.

```
{% for book in books%}
    {% if author.id is book.author.id %}
      <li>
        <a href="{{ book.get_absolute_url }}">{{ book.title }}</a> ({{book.author}})
      </li>
{% endif %}
```

This code do what i wanted but by sending all objects.
I hope you understand what i want.

Here is my models,views https://pastebin.com/yY6M5LUA

Comment: It doesn't make sense to filter on `Author.id`. Which author?

Comment: @DanielRoseman yeah ,that author should be pk of current page so there should be author__exact = pkOfAuthorOfCurrentPage but i dont know how to get current pages detail in this view ,,i think this is so confused

Comment: You need to show the rest of the view, and the URL.

Answer (score 0):

filter will send you a queryset not a objects, what you need to do is to get the objects corresponding to the need, for eg, `Book.objects.filter(author__exact=Author.id)[0]` will give you the first object from the queryset, so you get the object from here.

Comment: If this is the problem then how passing constant `1` is working ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a DetailView, so you already have the current author in the context. So there's actually no reason to do anything in the view - you can remove your `get_context_data` method. Instead, you can follow the reverse relationship in the template:

```
{% for book in author.book_set.all %}
  {{ book.title }}
{% endfor %}
```